# Dockerfile ARG substitution in a string in RUN command

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I want to substitute a variable in a string.

```
ARG w=world
RUN echo 'Hello $w'
```

I want the output to be `Hello world` but the actual output is `Hello $w`

Answer (score 25):

Docker doesn't expand ARG values in the RUN command. Instead, it injects the ARG as an environment variable. The shell itself expands the variable, and all of the Linux shells I've used behave differently based on the type of quote.

The single quotes direct the shell not to expand anything, and you only need to escape the single quotes and escape characters. While the double quotes include variable expansion along with many other escape characters. See the man page on your shell for more details.

So the solution as you've already found is:

```
RUN echo "Hello $w"
```

Comment: Just out of interest is there anyway to see the expanded value, could be useful for debugging. ?

Comment: @choco In Linux, `env` will loose all environment variables that have been passed. And to show a command with the expanded variables, I'll either run `set -x` or prefix a single command with echo. E.g. if the command was `ls $x` I'd run `echo debugging: ls $x`

Answer (score 7):

`RUN echo "Hello $w"` works fine. The ARG is resolved within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you are concatenating strings, you will need to include `{}` around the ARG value.  For instance:

```
ARG w=world
RUN echo "Hello_${w}_again"
```